# alarmManager set an alarm to work at exact time instead of fractions

Tags: android, time, calendar, alarm

In my app I have the below

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i= new Intent("MY_ALARM_NOTIFICATION");
    i.setClass(this, OnAlarmReceive.class);
    i.putExtra("id", id);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //
    Calendar timeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    timeCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    timeCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    timeCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month) - 1);
    timeCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

However, this might return to me `1414526788222` which is `Tue, 28 Oct 2014 20:06:28 GMT`, but what I want is `Tue, 28 Oct 2014 20:06:00` (without the seconds. I always wanted the seconds to be 00)....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the seconds to zero.

`timeCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);`

Comment: thanks. sometimes i miss some easy stuff during the AMs... thanks buddy